# lib32-ncurses not installing into rootfs

Tags: linux, debugging, embedded-linux, yocto, ncurses

I am trying to add 32-bit `ncurses` into my root file system of a Yocto based image.

I am using intel yocto bsp sumo branch

Here is my `local.conf`:

```
require conf/multilib.conf
DEFAULTTUNE_virtclass-multilib-lib32 = "x86"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " dpkg gnutls lib32-glibc lib32-libgcc lib32-libstdc++ lib32-gnutls lib32-freetype lib32    -libx11 lib32-ncurses lib32-dpkg python3-six"
```

ncurses folder is present in tmp

```
build/tmp/work/x86-pokymllib32-linux/lib32-ncurses/6.0+20171125-r0
```

The image folder is created and has the libraries

```
/tmp/work/x86-pokymllib32-linux/lib32-ncurses/6.0+20171125-r0/image/lib
libncurses.so.5  libncurses.so.5.9  libncursesw.so.5  libncursesw.so.5.9  libtinfo.so.5  libtinfo.so.5.9
```

But these files are not present in root file system.

How can I debug or what should be my next step to get it into root file system. Which log files should I look

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use `IMAGE_INSTALL += lib32-ncurses` or `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = lib32-ncurses` in your image recipe or `conf/local.conf`

Comment: It's already present. Check question

Comment: I am unable to find libncurses.so in packages-split folder. Where do you think it is  missing

Comment: I see libncurses.so in packages-split/lib32-ncurses-dev , what should I do to add it in rootfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer after posting query in Yocto mailing list.

```
$ oe-pkgdata-util find-path */libncurses.so*
ncurses-libncurses: /lib64/libncurses.so.5
ncurses-libncurses: /lib64/libncurses.so.5.9
ncurses-dbg: /lib64/.debug/libncurses.so.5.9
lib32-ncurses-dbg: /lib/.debug/libncurses.so.5.9
ncurses-dev: /usr/lib64/libncurses.so
lib32-ncurses-dev: /usr/lib/libncurses.so
lib32-ncurses-libncurses: /lib/libncurses.so.5.9
lib32-ncurses-libncurses: /lib/libncurses.so.5
```

So including `lib32-ncurses-libncurses` in `local.conf` will solve the problem

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += "lib32-ncurses-libncurses"
```

Answer (score 1):

> I see libncurses.so in packages-split/lib32-ncurses-dev , what should I do to add it in rootfs

The default recipe won't install the development package into the rootfs unless explicitly instructed to do so. You can add this to your local.conf for quick testing:

`IMAGE_INSTALL_append += lib32-ncurses-dev`

You should now see the contents of `packages-split/lib32-ncurses-dev` inside your ncurses `image` folder and subsequently image rootfs.

There is a similar approach for dbg packages as well.